# detect mouse stop time interval

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using the below `javascript` code to detect mouse stop interval after `500ms`

```
document.onmousemove = (
var onmousestop = function() {
    alert("mouse stopped moving");
  }, thread;

  return function() {
    clearTimeout(thread);
    thread = setTimeout(onmousestop, 500);
  };
})();
```

is there a way to detect how long the mouse has stopped moving and execute a code if the mouse stopped moving for `500ms` any help would be appreciated. thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: Actually your code does this already!? Anytime user does not move the mouse for 500ms there would be an alert. _Also edit your code to make it of a correct syntax -- `onmousemove = (function(){`_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use this plugin, 
this is a smart efficent code to track mousestop events.

http://richardscarrott.co.uk/posts/view/jquery-mousestop-event

For example working example: http://jsfiddle.net/brunis/wLu4V/

```
$( 'html' ).bind('mousestop', function() {
  // do timeout here
});
$( 'html' ).mousemove(function( event ) {
    // clear timeout here
});
```

I did not use the mousestop, you can if you want, but it will need some extra work;
the mousestop only tracked one mousestop per mouseenter.

If you want to use mousestop event plugin, you can easily only use this code:

```
$.mousestopDelay = 500; // Wait 500 ms before triggering the mousestop event
$( 'html' ).bind('mousestop', function() {
    alert("Mouse stop + 500 MS!");
});
```

Comment: What about the 500ms part?

Comment: will add this to the answer